# Refactoring functions passed as properties from es5 to es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently in the process of refactoring my code from es5 to es6, but have hit a wall when it came to refactoring...

```
<li className="pure-menu-item" onClick={this.props.onClick}></li>
```

How would I bind this function which is passed when the component is created, in the constructor?

```
class NavButton extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this._handleClick = this.props.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="pure-menu-item" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <a className="pure-menu-link">{this.props.text}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
  _handleClick() {
    alert('test');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your ES5 code and the ES6 you thought would work

Comment: @Bergi Hi, I have included it in the post. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<li className="pure-menu-item" onClick={this._handleClick}>` ?

Comment: @mfirry But I want to be able to pass a function to the NavButton component as a param?

Comment: You want to be able to write something like `<NavButton text="some text" onClick={{someFunc}} />` right?

Comment: Give this a try http://pastie.org/10742139

Answer (score 0):

You're making a `_handleClick` method on your class, but then overwriting it in the constructor with `this._handleClick = this.props.onClick.bind(this);`, and then ignoring it completely by passing  `onClick={this.props.onClick}`.

I suspect what you really want is to `bind` your `onClick` function to the component that owns it in that component's constructor, rather than in the component it's being passed through.

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve your issue?

```
class NavButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="pure-menu-item" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
        <a className="pure-menu-link">{this.props.text}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

NavButton.propTypes = {
  handleClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  text: React.PropTypes.string
};
```